# How to check if a value is greater than or equal to another?

Tags: bash, scripts

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true; do
    if xprintidle | grep -q 3000; then
      xdotool mousemove_relative 1 1
    fi
done
```

Currently I'm able to check if `xprintidle` is equal to 3000 and then if it is, execute `xdotool`. But I want to check if `xprintidle` is greater or equal than 3000 and then execute `xdotool`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you just have take 2 min to google your question about bash, you will have found it faster than here

Comment: I was googling about 1h and coulnd't find any answer. Even here some of the answers didn't work for me.

Comment: @damadam To be honest, googling only works when you know the buzzwords to google for.

Comment: @damadam So? This way it’s useful for others. Let’s [be nice](https://askubuntu.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: While research effort is indeed something that is encouraged before asking questions, and OP could have definitely found something, question will be beneficial for others. Everyone uses different search term, and this question with its wording can be of service too.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
if [ $xprintidle -ge 3000 ]; then
  [...stuff...]
```

Here's a quick explanation:

- **gt** - greater than
- **ge** - greater or equal than
- **$(** ... **)** becomes the output of the command inside the parentheses

Comment: Because this uses `[` instead of `[[` and doesn't quote the command substitution, this doesn't quite capture OP's intention. It allows `xprintidle` to add additional conditions to test, like outputting `1 -o 2000` will also cause it to pass the condition. Not really a problem on its own, but it's bad practice. If later another insignificant bug, maybe in `xprintidle`, allows someone untrustworthy to prefix the output. You may also consider that bug to be no problem on its own, but together they can amount to something.

Comment: If `xprintidle` is not a command rather than a variable it should be `$xprintidle`

Comment: @alper thnx, edited accordingly

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`bash`’s Arithmetic Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr) directly to compare integers:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while :; do
  (( $(xprintidle) >= 3000 )) && xdotool mousemove_relative 1 1
  sleep 0.5
done
```

If you just want the single command, `&&` is a simple way. Alternatively, use `if`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while :; do
  if (( $(xprintidle) >= 3000 )); then
    xdotool mousemove_relative 1 1
  fi
  sleep 0.5
done
```

I added a `sleep` call to the loop to pause for half a second each run – adapt it as needed.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to sleep a while thus preventing the loop from going berserk.

Comment: @PerlDuck Tbh, I don’t even understand fully what *the user's idle time* is – I’ll leave that to OP…

Answer (score 4):

To say if number is greater or equal to other you can use `-ge`. So your code can look like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true; do
    if [[ $(xprintidle) -ge 3000 ]]; then
        xdotool mousemove_relative 1 1
    fi
done
```